# What languages does iOS's system font (Helvetica Neue) support?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, fonts

Does anyone happen to know which languages the iOS system font (Helvetica Neue) supports? Have Googled but have been unable to get a specific answer on this, does Apple list this anywhere?

Comment: On your Mac, you can use the font inspector to see which character ranges in the Unicode are supported. You should not worry - if the system supports a certain language, the system will find a font to render the text.

Comment: @0x7fffffff As far as I know, the Apple-licensed fonts are slightly different from their commercial variants. So information from Linotype may be misleading or incorrect about the Apple variant.

Comment: @LeoNatan - Should've said that I'm trying to find a font that supports a lot of languages because in cocoa-touch, it won't find an appropriate font for you - least in CoreText).

Comment: @CoDEFRo Gotcha. One way to overcome this issue is to provide your own font, perhaps one of the free fonts, where you know precisely which glyphs are available.